# how do I encrypt a password and then retrieve it and match it against user input?

Tags: php

> There is no decrypt function. The crypt() function uses a one-way
>   algorithm.

I have never used encryption.  Could somebody explain how to use it when encypting passwords?

```
echo "<br>" . $salt = '$2a$07$2';
echo "<br>" . $digest = crypt('mypassword', $salt);

$user_input = "mypassword" ;

if (crypt($user_input, $digest) == $digest) {echo "<br>".$fine ;}
```

how can i encrpt a password and retrieve it?

Comment: You can't retrieve password after encryption. You can encrypt some text (user's suggested password) and compare it with old encryption result (compare hashes). IF they are equal - passwords match.

Comment: Just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php, follow the examples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that is easy , all of you have to do  is the following

in the beginning when you get the user password you can encrypt it using md5 method

```
$password= md5($_POST["passwordFromRegistrationForm"]);//getting the password from  registration form and encrypt it .
```

now you can write a mysql query to insert it to your database.

and when you want to match the password stored in your database with the password came from logIn form , you have to retrieve the password which is stored in the database  and then you have to encrypt the password which came from the logIn Form using the same encryption method and then make comparison between the tow passwords .

```
$retrievedPassword = write a select statement to retrieve it from database; 
$passwordUserLogInFrom =  md5($_POST["passwordFromLogInForm"]);
if($retrievedPassword == $passwordUserLogInFrom )
{
   //write your code
}
```

Comment: md5 also shouldn't be used. There are a lot better hashing functions, please use something like bcrypt.

Comment: can you explain for me  why we should not use md5 ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash